# dbt - snowflake - validation function

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have this model and macro but they are not working:

models/model_1.sql

```
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        unique_key = ['error', 'file', 'rejected_record'],
        incremental_strategy='merge',
        merge_exclude_columns = ['error', 'file', 'rejected_record']
    )
}}

SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALIDATE({{ source('sources_raw','table_1') }}, JOB_ID => '{{ log_error_validate() }}'))
```

macros/log_error_validate.sql

```
{% macro log_error_validate() %}

    {% set query_id %}
        SELECT QUERY_ID 
        FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_WAREHOUSE(WAREHOUSE_NAME => 'WH_NAME')) 
        WHERE 
            DATABASE_NAME LIKE 'DB_NAME' AND SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND QUERY_TYPE LIKE 'COPY' 
        ORDER BY START_TIME DESC 
        LIMIT 1
    {% endset %}
 
    {% set results = run_query(query_id) %}

    {% if execute %}
        {% for row in results.rows %}
            {% set retval = row[1] %}
            {{ return(retval) }}
        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

The error is the following:

```
Database Error in model model_1 (models/model_1.sql)
01:01:48    002018 (22023): SQL compilation error:
01:01:48    Invalid argument [Invalid Job UUID provided.] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant.
```

Any thoughts? The resulting code is:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM 
   TABLE(VALIDATE(raw_dev.bdot.adq_cuotas_anu_hist, JOB_ID => ))
```

The macro is not working

Comment: _Invalid Job UUID provided_ Are you sure `JOB_ID =>` is correct syntax? It seems like it needs a parameter value. I can't find any reference to the `=>` operator in snowflake but looking at other code examples it seems like it needs a value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67101328/error-while-getting-validation-error-in-last-data-load-query

Comment: hi @Nick.McDermaid , yeah for sure the function needs a value in the JOB_ID => parameter, the result that i post above is what DBT is interpreting. Thats we i call the macro right there to obtain that job id but that part is actually the one that is not working

Comment: as per you last question, the resulting SQL is invalid, and thus the error message. You already know how to provide a valid value of `'_last'` which I showed, "working" now it seems to you some code the fetches a UUID, and it does work. So the would seem you need to debug that. I would suggest looking at the querry history in your snowflake instance to workout what your `log_error_validate` function is running.

Comment: Is it possible that query `query_id ` in `log_error_validate` returns no rows?

Comment: hi @Nick.McDermaid i actually debug the macro using ipdb and in effect that query inside query_id is "Undefined" i think the problem is with the '=>' but thats how the query has to be formed in snowflake, i don't know what to do.. i need the result of that query.. geez

Comment: The problem is not the `=>`, it's that you don't have a parameter value after it. It should look like `JOB_ID => {some value}`. I guess since your query returns nothing, that your template puts nothing after the `=>` Do you know what should be there?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yeah after the JOB_ID => has to be a varchar, that id is returned from this macro JOB_ID => '{{ log_error_validate() }}', the problem actually is in the query inside the macro, this query: {% set query_id %}
        SELECT QUERY_ID FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.QUERY_HISTORY_BY_WAREHOUSE(WAREHOUSE_NAME => 'WH_NAME')) 
        WHERE DATABASE_NAME LIKE 'DB_NAME' AND SCHEMA_NAME LIKE 'SCHEMA_NAME' AND QUERY_TYPE LIKE 'COPY' 
        ORDER BY START_TIME DESC LIMIT 1
    {% endset %}  . This query is giving me an error and i think is the => that has inside